# How to get likes_count with only publish_action permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, restfb

I have a web application that uses Facebook API. Now, I'm facing with an issue on getting the total of likes from a user's post.

I have a long lived "userToken" valid for 2 months with the following scopes: public_profile, email, manage_pages, publish_actions

I use "POST /feed" to send a link into the user's timeline and I get a post ID.

Then, I try to get the total of likes for this post with "GET /{POST_ID}/likes?sumary=true" and I get ZERO likes even if the post has many likes.

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 0
  }
}
```

I tried to use only "GET /{POST_ID}" to get post information and I get the following json response:

```
{
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100
      }
}
```

I have this issue only when I post to a user's timeline. However, when I post to a Facebook page, I can get the post ID and the numer of likes.

I made a test by adding read_stream scope and I can get the post information. However I read in API documentation that this permission has a limited use: "This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available"

Then, I started to check other applications that get post likes and I noticed that they are using only public_profile, email, manage_pages, publish_actions. They are not using read_stream.

So, my question is how they can get this information only with these scopes?

I hope anyone of you will be able to help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check, if the post is `public`.

If you have the post id of a public post you can fetch the likes simply by requesting the endpoint you already mentioned.

To get your feed you need the `read_stream` or `user_posts` permission.